# How do I run source code in a mac terminal?

Tags: c, macos, terminal

Please please help me, I am a computer illiterate female looking to convert a group of (.cng files) into jpegs. I found a source code on a blog that instructs me to

> Build it, then run it with something like this:
>
> cng2jpg /path/to/images/199x/1990101/*.cng

[Here is a link to the source code](https://diplograph.net/files/2012-06/cng2jpg.c)

Does anyone know how I can run the source code to convert the files?

[Here is a link to the blog post for reference for what exactly I am doing](https://diplograph.net/posts/decoding_the_complete_national_geographic_images)

Answer (score 0):

First, put the source code into a file named `cng2jpg.c`. Then open a terminal, navigate with `cd` into the directory where you placed that file and type

```
cc -o cng2jpg cng2jpg.c
```

This creates the program `cng2jpg`. You can execute it by typing

```
path/to/cng2jpg input_file.cng
```

where `path/to/cng2jpg` is the path where `cng2jpg` was generated in the previous step.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I gave that a try and was able to create the program, however when I put i the path/to/cng2jpg I get a -bash: FLASHDRIV/CompleteNatGEO/disc1/images/199x/19960501: No such file or directory the path above being the program location. Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Don't forget the `/*.cng` at the end!

Comment: Thanks again, but this seems to have mixed things up even further. To break it down I have created a program called cng2jpg which is now found at /Volumes/FLASHDRIV/CompleteNatGEO/disc1/images/199x/19960501 if I want to execute the program and convert the files what exactly should I input? I'm not sure what input_file.cng is meant to represent nor where I should place /*.cng Thanks again!

Comment: @C. Fo Open a terminal. Navigate to that directory with `cd path` where `path` is the path where you can find these files. Then type `./cng2jpg *.cng` to do the conversion. If everything works out, you should find a pile of jpg images in the directory. Please tell me if it worked.